# How to get WebElement "label" for a simple iOS app ? Searching by tag name fails with Invalid locator strategy"

Tags: ios, selenium, functional-testing, appium

I am trying to test an iOS app in Java using appium/selenium. When I look for a 'label' `WebElement` using `findElementbyTagName("label")`, I get an error saying:

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: Invalid locator strategy: tag name
```

When I search for it by Id I don't find the element.

Following is the xml snippet

```
<label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="0" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="5W0-NU-uUg">
    <rect key="frame" x="132" y="361" width="42" height="27"/>
    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
    <color key="textColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="darkTextColor"/>
    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Where are you getting that XML snippet from? What version of Appium are you running? I haven't seen XML output like that before

Comment: This XML is from Xcode. I got this from XML editor for the view

Comment: When trying to find elements, you need to use the Appium inspector, it's in Appium.app. [you can download from this site](http://appium.io/). Another way is to print the webdriver's `pageSource`

Comment: **Pagesource helped in understanding the label. It can be called by className UIAStaticText, which is case sensitive.**

Comment: Yes, in 1.0 they did a big migration of classes/tags from 'label' to things like UIAStaticText. All existing xpaths would've also been affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[The tag name locator strategy was deprecated](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/2440)** in Appium Versions >= 1.0

You should use `findElementByClassName('UIAStaticText')`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was findElementByClassName("UIAStaticText").
Webdriver's pageSource (using getPageSource), helped in identifying the class name.

Comment: You should really use Appium Inspector though. It'll help a ton. It visualizes the entire DOM in a GUI and lets you navigate through it -- giving you info on xpaths, names, values, etc of the elements on the screen